# Download specific tab of xlsx file from Google Drive in R

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-drive-api

The partial solution to my problem was provided here: [Download xlsx file from Google Drive in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65571739/download-xlsx-file-from-google-drive-in-r/77870621#77870621)

All I want to do is modify the code below so that I can chose a specific tab. The code below only seems to pull the first tab. I have tried to add sheet = 2 or or sheet = "filename" without any success. Here is the code:

```
library(googledrive)

dl <- drive_download(
 as_id("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17ZhE3nxqtGYNzeADMzU02YzfKU9H9f5j/edit#gid=1748893795"),
  path = 'temp1.xlsx', 
  overwrite = TRUE, 
  type = "xlsx")


Three_Time_Series <- readxl::read_excel('temp1.xlsx')
```

How do I modify the code to pull a specific tab?

Comment: Have you tried changing the GID in the url? Each tab has a different GID. 





[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17ZhE3nxqtGYNzeADMzU02YzfKU9H9f5j/edit\#gid=](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17ZhE3nxqtGYNzeADMzU02YzfKU9H9f5j/edit#gid=1748893795)(GID of Specific Tab)"

Comment: `readxl::read_excel('temp1.xlsx', sheet = "my tab")` should work.

Comment: Hi! Please post this as an answer this way  we can help other community members that have the same question and get answers.

Comment: @Babanana How do I do that?